Degrees of freedom is off by a multiple of one of my factors (Two-way ANOVA in R)
I've run a two way repeated measures ANOVA in R and the degrees of freedom for the residual seem to be off.
My dataset looks like this: Behavioral Intox Data
**and my code for the ANOVA:
behint_rm_anova <- aov(Intox_score ~ Point * Condition + Error(ID/Point), data = Behavioral_intox_data_v4_for_R)`

summary(behint_rm_anova)

**produces these results:
> Error: Within  
> Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
> Point            11  55.82   5.075   6.626 5.81e-10 ***  
> Condition         2  36.82  18.410  24.036 1.96e-10 ***  
> Point:Condition  22  29.18   1.326   1.732   0.0232 *    
> Residuals       312 238.97   0.766 


If i'm not mistaken, the residuals df should be: Total observations (360) - levels of factor A (3) x levels of factor B (12). 360-36 = 324.
I've looked at past posts here and I believe I've included the correct error term. I also changed "Point" to a factor using:
Behavioral_intox_data_v4_for_R$Point <- as.factor(Behavioral_intox_data_v4_for_R$Point)

Changing that to a factor fixed an issue with my df for "Point" that I initially encountered, but did not fix this issue.
I also tried changing "ID" to a factor as well as "Day" using the same code as above, but when I tried this, it produced an ANOVA table that was missing "Condition" entirely:
Error: ID:Point  
                 Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
Point            11 114.93  10.448  13.942 <2e-16 ***  
Point:Condition  22  30.32   1.378   1.839 0.0135 *    
Residuals       297 222.58   0.749 

I'm unsure why changing "ID" to a factor would remove the "Condition" part of the output all together. Also Unsure how I could restructure my r code to produce the correct residual df.
My data table

Where can one get the data? Or at least post a minimal reproducible sample of the data.

I'm sorry I realize now I included an image of the dataset but not a useable copy. From the searching I've done it seems like there isn't a simple way to paste my datatable here. Do you have a recommendation for how I should include the data table in a way that will be useable for those viewing my post?

It's ok. You can transform you data to a json or a dictionary.  Also, when formatting code, follow my example of the edits I made. To see how,  press edit below your post. You'll see that code is in between two lines with ```.

I'm looking up how to transform the data table and it looks like I need to use C# or python but I do not know either language. I pasted a snipet of the table and manually added double spaces after each line to hopefully make it somewhat readable. I apologize again, I'm finding myself very out of my depth trying to use R for analyses having little experience working with data like this before. Most of the language I come across in trying to learn these things is foreign to me.

ok. Try my suggested solution and let me know if it gives you what you expect.

I tried the suggested solution, but I'm still missing the "Condition" part of the output. I'm also a bit confused about how you arrived at the error term mentioned in your code for the ANOVA.

Not having access to your data I created a sample dataframe. Now, I think this is the error:
You’ve calculated the expected residual df as 324(360−36=324), thereby assuming there are no missing values and perfect balance in your dataset. Here's how this breakdown is typically considered:
Total observations: 360
Levels of Factor A (Point): 12
Levels of Factor B (Condition): 3
Interaction: 12*3=36
The degrees of freedom for the residuals in a repeated measures design would be calculated by adjusting for all these effects within each subject. Assuming =30 subjects, each measured 12 times under 3 conditions. The number you've calculated (324) seems not to account for subtracting the degrees of freedom for each subject, as done in typical RM ANOVA settings:
Residual df=(n−1)*(levels of Point*levels of Condition−1)
Residual df=(30−1)*(36−1)=29*35=1015

Try to do it this way:
set.seed(123) 

ID <- rep(1:30, each=36)  ditions)
Condition <- rep(c("T", "F", "M"), each=12, times=30)  
Point <- rep(1:12, times=90)  
Intox_score <- sample(1:100, 1080, replace=TRUE)  

Behavioral_intox_data <- data.frame(ID, Condition, Point, Intox_score)

str(Behavioral_intox_data)

Behavioral_intox_data$ID <- as.factor(Behavioral_intox_data$ID)
Behavioral_intox_data$Condition <- as.factor(Behavioral_intox_data$Condition)
Behavioral_intox_data$Point <- as.factor(Behavioral_intox_data$Point)

if (!("stats" %in% .packages(TRUE))) {
  library(stats)
}

behint_rm_anova <- aov(Intox_score ~ Point * Condition + Error(ID/(Point * Condition)), data = Behavioral_intox_data)
summary(behint_rm_anova)



which gives
Error: ID
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 29  12639   435.8               

Error: ID:Point
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
Point      11  17310  1573.7   1.828 0.0485 *
Residuals 319 274567   860.7                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: ID:Condition
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Condition  2   1068   533.8   0.662  0.519
Residuals 58  46740   805.9               

Error: ID:Point:Condition
                 Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Point:Condition  22  22946  1043.0   1.283  0.174
Residuals       638 518647   812.9             

REMEMBER: THIS IS DATA I CREATED. CHECK WITH YOUR ACTUAL DATA.

In searching for how degrees of freedom are calculated to try an manually resolve this issue, I hadn't come across anything describing subtracting degrees of freedom for each subject (unless I am misunderstanding what you mean here, which is possible). The formula you've written out underneath that paragraph makes sense, but I don't understand the results of the code you provided. I don't see degrees of freedom for the Condition factor alone, which is one of the issues I was having after updating my code. Thanks again for your assistance, I can add detail or clarify if helpful.
